# Fixing Flash error 1046 against SoundEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, types, compiler-errors

I'm trying publish an old .fla (I'm not the author)
 after doing some minor graphical edits, but the complier is reporting:

> 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:
>   SoundEvent.

The source it points me to is:

> private function volumeHandler(evt:SoundEvent):void {
>   this.soundTransform = evt.soundTransform; }

Here is the sum of the source: http://snipplr.com/view/79370/fixing-flash-error-1046-against-soundevent/

I'm a little over my head here, any help would be appreciated. I found [this thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/749266?tstart=0) and monkied around with some of the suggestions there to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import fl.video.SoundEvent;` 
is not defined in sdk...  I think you use some library and it's not imported in your project...

Comment: I think it is defined: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/SoundEvent.html right?

Comment: It' not defined in standart sdk, you must import fl. library

Comment: Can someone tell me how I inmport this library? I added these paths: these paths:

""C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Common\First Run\Classes
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\projects\Flash\src\fl
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0""

Comment: if you have *.swc you can add it in your project lib directory, rigth click and than add to library

Comment: Needed to add this class path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\FLVPlayback"

Comment: I'm not sure in my answer but if you add this library in C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS6\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\libs 
it'll be right

Comment: if my answer will be helpful tell me